# What is the use of the featured tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

On Stack Overflow there is the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag. Here on Meta it is a mod-only tag ([featured](/questions/tagged/featured)), where the use is clear:

> **A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the main site, in a special sidebar, in the questions list, and when viewing individual questions.**

But on SO itself:

> **give special prominence, attention, or publicity to items in a collection.**

Now how/when to use that tag? I have no idea in which case to use that tag.

Comment: If you look at the questions that use this tag, it looks like a meta tag that should be burninated. It doesn't mean anything and should be removed from any question that has it.

Comment: [tag:featured] Has 190 uses, though. That'll take a little more work.

Comment: @Oded 9 posts only? For some reason I see 139 posts.

Comment: Oh. I was on the "frequent" tab. @AzizShaikh

Comment: Looking through some of the questions, I see a lot of [WordPress questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured%20wordpress?mode=all).  Seems it might be a "feature" (no pun intended) of WordPress?  Perhaps it doesn't need burninated and just needs to have a better tag wiki, and maybe get renamed so it isn't misused?

Comment: Looks like the wordpress [dynamic-featured-image] tag gone awry.  Common mishap with drastically wordy tags like that, users just don't type the dashes.

Answer (score 14):

Aside from the fact it's not a valid tag, as confirmed by Oded♦ -

> Now how to use that tag? I have no idea in which case to use that tag.

Then quite simply, *don't*.

Tags should be relevant to the question, not the other way around.

Comment: This is wrong. The featured tag has some uses, and a rename is probably in order. The uses can be seen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408079/12708583