# The tag wiki itself says it "should not be used", so Burninate [featured]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

According to the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag wiki:

> give special prominence, attention, or publicity to items in a collection.
>
> ---
>
> This tag should not be used as discussed [here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310715/what-is-the-use-of-the-featured-tag).

If the tag wiki says that it **should not be used**, why does it exist?

I suggest we burninate it. It only has 134 questions, so re-tagging and editing will not take too long.

Comment: How [featured] should this tag be?

Comment: Thank you for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: @Druzion There have been issues with burninations in the past, where users don't wait for consensus and just start editing the tags out of the posts. They _only_ remove the tags and don't fix other issues with the post. While a tag is being burninated, it's a good time to edit the questions that need it, close the questions that should be closed, and delete questions that should be deleted. Someone removing the tags without doing any of that makes cleaning those questions up much harder. And the process in the last link is being tested, so not everyone knows how that process works yet.

Comment: It would be ironic if this post were to become [meta-tag:featured].

Comment: @Tunaki: Can you tweak that boilerplate so it doesn't sound like you're decrying editing the tag out at all? What you're really trying to work against is *mere* mass-re-tagging without any other work done to the questions, but that's not very clearly expressed.

Comment: @Tunaki: Yes, but burninating **is** mass-editing! It's just that it's not *just* mass-editing. It's also close-voting/flagging, making other edits, and so on and so forth. Again, that's very poorly expressed and should be clarified.

Answer (score 5):

As noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310715/what-is-the-use-of-the-featured-tag), [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) (on Main) is a meta-tag that doesn't provide any value to the question.

Here are the official criteria:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. The tag does not describe the contents of the question to which it is applied to, and it could be applied on any question. At best, it could relate to anything from featured images to featured products.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's not about programming, especially considering the uses for it currently.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Any useful information that the tag might bring could instead be included in the title or the question itself.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. Once again, it could range from featured images to featured products to featured posts.

---

Here's an excerpt from the tag info:

> This tag should NOT BE USED.

This meta-tag should be burninated.

<sub>Note: There seem to be a lot of questions on here about WordPress; a few re-taggings to [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image) may be necessary.</sub>