# This tag should not be [featured] on Main

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

As noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310715/what-is-the-use-of-the-featured-tag), [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) (on Main) is a meta-tag that doesn't provide any value to the question.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. The tag does not describe the contents of the question to which it is applied to, and it could be applied on any question. At best, it could relate to anything from featured images to featured products.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's not about programming, especially considering the uses for it currently.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Any useful information that the tag might bring could instead be included in the title or the question itself.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. Once again, it could range from featured images to featured products to featured posts.

---

Here's an excerpt from the tag info:

> This tag should NOT BE USED.

Can we burninate this meta-tag?

Note: There seem to be a lot of questions on here about WordPress; a few re-taggings to [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image) may be necessary.

Reasons why this should be reopened:

The proposed duplicate doesn't have any answers (other than my own), hasn't been looked at in more than a year, doesn't go over the official criteria for burnination, and never got more than 20 votes.

Comment: If you take away our features we'll all revert back to IE6.  Why would you do that to us??? ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver IE6 *was* a feature, or do you not remember IE4?

Comment: @rgettman The duplicate doesn't have any answers and hasn't been looked at in more than a year. It also doesn't go over the official criteria for burnination. Plus, this has a better title.

Comment: If anything, the other one should be closed as a dupe of this one. Or does the "use the better rather than the older" rule not apply to Meta?