# Burninate [featured]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

On Stack Overflow we have a tag [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured).

Here is its Excerpt and Wiki:

> This tag should NOT BE USED.

> Give special prominence, attention, or publicity to items in a collection.
>
> This tag should not be used as discussed [here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310715/what-is-the-use-of-the-featured-tag).

Given that on the referenced Meta post from 2015 the consensus in the comments was to remove that tag.

Why would we keep a tag that shouldn't be used?  It's simply confusing, and worse, there are 145 questions tagged with [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured).  Let's burninate it!

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it doesn't describe the contents, and it isn't unambiguous.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It doesn't define a programming concept.

3. Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

Unless you consider the fact that the OP wants attention, no.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

It doesn't really mean anything other that treating something in a special way.

Comment: See [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/11682469) and [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/11682469)

Comment: @JeanneDark Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?  No.  Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?  No.

Comment: I invite you to look at a few high-voted posts under the [meta-tag:burninate-request] tag to get some inspiration how such request is expected to look like...

Comment: As for the inevitable "Why is this downvoted?". It is downvoted because your initial revision was utterly unclear and lacking the criteria to conclude if the tag should be burninated at all . This is all explained in the tag wiki of [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) as well as in the guidance Jeanne linked to earlier.

Comment: @rene Does this edit make it better?

Comment: Hardly, but I guess we should praise the little bit of effort you put into it.

Comment: @rene What more is there to say?  It's an obviously useless tag that _says_ it shouldn't be used.

Comment: "It doesn't define a concept." - featuring is a concept. "Unless you consider the fact that the OP wants attention, no." - it highlights that it involves something about featuring (which is a thing on certain websites). "It doesn't really mean anything." - then neither does your post, any of our comments, or any languages. It has meanings - it's not gibberish. And to be clear, I'm not taking a stance on the tag, but you're NOT making a good case for burnination, even if it qualified

Comment: @Zoe Allowing anyone to add it makes it useless, the point of [meta-tag:featured] on meta is that a moderator considers it useful enough to show it on the main site's sidebar.  Not so on main.

Comment: @Anonymous Did you actually go over the questions in this tag? People don't use the tag to try and make their question *featured* as in Meta. It actually talks mostly about *featured images* in WordPress... 118/145 questions area also tagged `wordpress`. In that case another option here is to retag into `featured-image` instead...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Then why does it say in the tag wiki, "this tag should NOT be used"?  Why would a tag that shouldn't be used be helpful?

Comment: Because someone decided to write it there?

Comment: @Tomerikoo If it shouldn't be used, what purpose does it have?

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying that it has a purpose. I'm just saying that your argument of people using it to make their question featured is wrong...

Comment: As a 20k user, right now, I could go ahead and add "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!" to any tag I feel is even remotely ambiguous or vague (disregarding the mild abuse this constitutes). A tag containing "Do not use" in any shape or form is not an indicator of anything, as Tomerikoo indirectly hinted at. Also, don't drag meta into this - by that metric, we should have a discussion tag on main because we allow it on meta. A tag having a special meaning on one site shouldn't and doesn't affect the meaning of a tag with the same name on other sites

Comment: @Zoe I'm referring to the fact that it says it should be used for giving special attention to a tag.  "As a 20k user, right now, I could go ahead and add "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!" to any tag I feel is even remotely ambiguous or vague." - yes, thanks for telling me you could abuse your privileges to artificially cause burnination...

Comment: I think you're missing the point that this is ***NOT*** a reason for burnination in the first place...

Comment: @Tomerikoo What isn't?

Comment: Re. point 3 again, if you look at the tags, you'll notice that there's an apparent majority of wordpress-related questions - in fact, there's only about 30 or so that aren't tagged wordpress, the bulk of which seem to still be related to CMEs, and it's mostly used when there's content on their own site they're trying to highlight.

Comment: And no, anyone using their privs to do that should never, ever artificially cause a burnination, and you know why? Because meta stands between the tag wiki and a burnination, meaning it's filtered out by requiring an actual reason beyond the tag wiki having "do not use" and not knowing that "featured" has a meaning in the english language...

Comment: @Zoe A tag that [users agreed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310715/8384089) should not be used should be burninated...

Comment: Or retagged - see rene's answer. Again, just because a tag is recommended not to be used doesn't mean the best future action is to remove the tag and assume everything about it is bad

Comment: At least it has an excerpt and wiki, which might place it above a lot of other tags.

Answer (score 19):

I propose we don't burninate this tag.

Instead we do kind of what Hans Passant hinted on [in a comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310715/what-is-the-use-of-the-featured-tag#comment273805_310715).

> Looks like the wordpress [dynamic-featured-image] tag gone awry. Common mishap with drastically wordy tags like that, users just don't type the dashes.

Currently there are 145 question in the tag [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) with only 1 closed. 88 zero scored questions, 8 negative scored.
There are [118 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D+%5Bwordpress%5D+is%3Aq) tagged both [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) and [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). If my assumption is correct those 118 are roughly about [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image).

We clean-up the 27 questions that are not about [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). Once completed the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) gets merged / made a synonym of [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image).

My proposal requires a lot less effort and still allows for users of featured stuff in Wordpress to use the tag that then gets translated automagically to [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image).

It is suggested in the comments that the tag [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image) is too heavy as hammer. Instead the re-tagging should happen to (new?) tags. Candidates are:

- [featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured-image)
- [wordpress-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-featured-image)

I suggest we extend this list with the purpose to be clean-up guidance.

Comment: Only hick-up with that is that the wiki of [[tag:dynamic-featured-image]] says: *"Dynamic Featured Image is a WordPress Plugin [...]"*. Not sure *all* WordPress questions are about that plug-in. Also from a quick scan not all questions are about featured images. Some are videos, posts etc.

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah, it could well be a swamp of off-topic-ness. I'm okay if a burn takes place, as long as it is based on evidence, not on text in the tag wiki. Feel free to write a competing answer to propose a different take.

Comment: I am not competing :) I support your suggestion, just adding that it should be done carefully, or maybe even have new `featured-...` tags instead

Comment: They are NOT all about "dynamic features image". In vanilla WordPress, every post can have a featured image, which is shows up as the banner on the post and in search results.

Comment: You are on to something but what @Laurel said is correct.  They should be retagged with something like [featured-image] (or maybe [wordpress-featured-image]?) rather than a specific plugin name.

Comment: @Laurel the featured image feature, is called like that just for the sake of [marketing people](https://wordpress.com/support/featured-images/), ie. non-programmers users, Programmers don't actually care what it's called, they just set the templates to use a image with some property (being the first or being marked as "featured").

Answer (score 4):

Most ([83](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D+%22featured+image%22+Wordpress+is%3Aq)?) of the questions in the featured tag are about the same, unambiguous concept: [WordPress featured images](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/).

In WordPress, a user will see a widget in the sidebar while editing a post that allows a "featured image" to be set. This image will be used in various parts of the theme, such as a banner on the post and when searching.

But the WordPress developer sees it a little differently: the code only refers to something called a "post thumbnail". Yet, it is one and the same as a featured image.

This is exactly the situation that tags are supposed to cover. Let's make a tag that works for this, in the way that's the least work:

- Rename featured to wordpress-featured-image (as there were some questions asking about "featured images" in other technologies)

  - Remove all other uses of the tag, perhaps making other new tags of needed. Some questions could benefit ([Woocommerce featured products](https://www.modernmarketingpartners.com/2015/01/19/set-featured-products-woocommerce/) — these are also WordPress questions, ones that aren't about featured images), some questions would not (I want to show this HTML on several pages, it is "featured")

    - Likely we won't need to retag anything to [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image) but it's there if it's needed. This tag is only to be used for questions asking about the *plugin* of that name
- Create and synonymize a wordpress-post-thumbnail tag into the featured image tag. Here's a question that would have benefited from the synonym as it doesn't even mention "featured":

  - [Wordpress post thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238940/6083675)

Answer (score 2):

So, it seems that we [flip-flopped this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310715/792066) and the saddest part is that we are just using flimsy arguments to keep this tag, instead of giving actual evidence that this tag is useful. First of all, Hans comment is wrong, the [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image) hasn't gone "awry", it's used for questions about the plugin, and there's no question about this plugin that doesn't use the plugin tag. [People aren't using the featured tag instead of the plugin tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22dynamic%22%20featured%20image%20%5Bfeatured%5D%20is%3Aq)

What's actually happening is that people are using this tag to literally mean "some featured thing". Be it [products](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46246614/792066), [images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577566/792066), [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22678746/792066), [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11740907/792066), etc. These questions only commonality is that they mention "featured", but these have no special representation in the language/frameworks that are relevant to programmers. If the common property of these was called "special" to mean that they are treated differently, it would be exactly the same: items that are put into an special position to distinguish from the other plebs. (In fact, in the featured image context, it's more likely some marketing speak that the CMS adopted.)

This tag can be safely removed. All questions have at least one useful tag that answerers actually follow to answer questions, [users with answers on the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/featured/topusers) seems to have answers just by accident, and all in all it's not a proper tag as defined by the help center in the way that it's ambiguous in the programming context what it actually means (since it's not even a programming concept).

Comment: You don't think clean-up is needed? Just a nuke tag by a mod will do?

Comment: @rene yeah, I didn't find anything closeable. Just average questions that happened to have the tag.

Comment: I mean... you're directly contradicting two answers that say exactly the opposite of what you're saying about the [[tag:dynamic-featured-image]]. Can you offer some evidence? Not asking you to personally go through every question, but [117 out of the 144](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=featured) questions tagged [[tag:featured]] (that's >80%) are also tagged [[tag:wordpress]]. That makes me at least somewhat skeptical of your statement that "*there's no question about this plugin that doesn't use the tag*".

Comment: @zcoop98 https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22dynamic%22+featured+image+%5Bfeatured%5D+is%3Aq There's only one question that has the featured tag that asks about the plugin, and that question also has the plugin tag. So, ask to the other answerers for evidence to their claims.