# What happened to the posts about Featured Images under the [featured] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Context: There's something built into WordPress (WP) called [Featured Images](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/). It's the image for each post that will likely show up in a theme when you're searching for posts or in your archive of posts. Some themes and plugins do other things with it. Significantly, it's not called a "featured image" in the code itself, where it is instead `the_post_thumbnail()`. Some people even call it a mix of things, like the "thumbnail image". This makes it difficult to search for.

The [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag (on the main site) used to group many of these questions together, though it was sometimes used for other purposes. Given the activity on the meta posts below the last time this was discussed, I was pretty sure that the consensus was ***not*** to just remove the tag from all main site questions:

- [Question at -6 suggesting the tag be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408077/6083675), tagged [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). (There was also some back and forth in the comments that may be relevant.)
- [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408079/6083675) at +18. It was edited after some feedback but the main thrust of it was "I propose we don't burninate this tag" and to replace it with a different tag.
- [My answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408097/6083675) at +4. I work with WordPress professionally, which I think counts for something, even if I'm not programming with it. My conclusion matches rene's after the edits: we should retag some of the questions and for the rest rename the  tag to [wordpress-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-featured-image).
- [Braiam's answer at +2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408094/6083675) saying to remove the tag.

Today I found that the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag no longer exists. It was not replaced like discussed. ([Example edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67795428/revisions)).

Why then was the tag removed completely? What did I miss?

Can someone help me find the questions where the tag was wrongfully removed so that [wordpress-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-featured-image) can be added? I tried to use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/681853/questions-with-a-specific-tag-at-first-revision-and-without-that-tag-now) but it timed out when I tried to search over too long a timespan, plus that only searches a single revision (the first).

Looking at [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image), I think it is being misused a lot (including on questions that used to have the featured tag that have no indication that they are about the plugin). Please note that this tag is supposed to be used for the plugin of that name and is not a synonym for vanilla WP Featured Images (in much the same way that a library like [jquery] is not the same as [javascript]).

Answer (score 8):

> The tag was burninated

The tag was not burninated.

In accordance with the highest scoring answer, I cleaned up the non-WP questions, and merged [featured] into [dynamic-featured-image]. Quoting rene's answer:

> Once completed the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) gets merged / made a synonym of [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image).

I read that slash as an "or", so I did not synonymize (particularly because `featured` is a somewhat useless synonym), and merged [featured] into [dynamic-featured-image]. You can also verify this yourself by [grabbing IDs from the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220430070002/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured), forming a URL you expect a question to be live at, and observe [how the featured tag is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72066134/ignore-the-selected-size-for-featured-image). The need for further cleanup was not clear from the answer.

This means that the answer to your second question:

> Most importantly, can someone help me find the questions where the tag was wrongfully removed

Is that all the questions are under [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image). Merger doesn't leave much of a trace to indicate that, however. Roughly 120 questions (according to the 2021 number of 46 [dynamic-featured-image] questions) were added to the tag, and that tag was already in need of cleanup, so it's not like extra work has been created. Looking at the archives for [dynamic-featured-image](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619133542/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image), I'm seeing questions that don't have anything to do with WordPress. I assume they're still on there, but I haven't looked.

If we're renaming the tag in its entirety, I'd recommend [wp-dynamic-featured-image-plugin], which is obnoxiously verbose, but extremely explicit about what it's actually for. Just specifying it's a plugin isn't necessarily enough to avoid non-WordPress interference.

Comment: Hey! Leave me out of this ... oh wait ... :/

Comment: "Not everyone is using that plugin; most aren't and now we don't even have an indication of who added tag to each question originally" - if the only indicator is a polluted tag (and I do mean before the merge; both tags were already bad and highly unreliable for topic determination), and there's absolutely no other way to identify what's being asked about, that's a close reason. Also worth noting that you now can clean up the tag on your own; there's no policies or bureaucracy for cleaning up the content of a tag under certain conditions. Retagging incorrectly tagged questions is one of those.

Comment: Can you rename the tag to [wordpress-featured-image]?

Comment: Renaming done .

Comment: Wait, now you actually made a mess. Now questions that are about the plugin are not anymore. Please, stop playing with buttons without knowing. Now we have to go back and recreate the tag instead of just removing it.

Comment: Excuse me? Laurel asked for the tag to be renamed to [wordpress-featured-image], and  I did. Given this question, I assumed "the tag" meant [dynamic-featured-image]. If that was a request for a retroactive rename of [featured], that's not possible. I'm not playing with buttons, I know exactly what I'm doing, but there's nothing I can do to avoid miscommunication

Comment: I fail to see how renaming a tag is "making a mess", at worst it can be renamed back.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine it makes a mess because it merged a good tag "dynamic-featured-image" which had [specific questions related to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408094/792066) which now doesn't exist anymore. Before it was simply removing the tag from the questions that were not the plugin, [which I was doing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418126/the-consensus-was-not-to-burninate-the-featured-tag-but-to-rename-the-tag-was/418128?noredirect=1#comment910255_418128), now I don't have an easy way to do so. So, yes, a mess.

Comment: I've removed [dynamic-featured-image] as a synonym so it can be re-created. If that's the retagging that was desired by Laurel to begin with, that means there's a dispute on what the tag is meant to be used for, and I'm not touching any more buttons until you lot figure out what you want to do with the tag. I cannot use mod tools to flip-flop between meanings over what appears to boil down to a disagreement about what the tag is for, particularly when every single step along the way so far has been diverging from the initial consensus outlined in rene's answer

Comment: To clarify, given what happened to the tag when it was originally merged, I did mean for the existing tag to be renamed [wordpress-featured-image], as few of the posts that were tagged were about the plugin anymore and any posts about the plugin are also about WP featured images. Maybe there really needs to be more of a process with this since what I thought was the consensus last time ("Instead the re-tagging should happen to (new?) tags.") wasn't. I would be fine with re-adding the new dynamic-featured-image to the few posts that obviously need it.

Comment: @Laurel is not only "add", it's remove and add, which was previously just remove.

Answer (score 2):

> The consensus was not to burninate the [featured] tag but to rename. The tag was burninated. What now?

The consensus was that the tag should not remain in the current state. In all proposals, there will no longer be a standalone feature tag. That's why it was burninated. It no longer exist. I still believe that having wordpress-featured-image tag to refer to such feature (:)) doesn't need to have its own tag, which is what happened.

If you find a question that doesn't ask about [dynamic-featured-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-featured-image), then remove it. I don't see what else needs to happen.